# permission error facebook api Json

Tags: android, json, facebook

I paste to browser [http://graph.facebook.com/search?q="John"](http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22John) but I get an error like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

How can I fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

all Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. the type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.

you can use this link to get your access token. make sure you have your app id & app secret.

http://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/

Comment: is this free ? because facebook wants to my phone number

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an Access Token in your query. It must be passed in the query as a parameter  `http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=John&access_token=<token>`.

It looks like you're new to Facebook Graph API. It's very easy to use API. Everything you want is there in the API documentation. For information regarding Access tokens you can refer here: [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Here is the documentation for Search API: [Search API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/). This will explain how to use this API with the help of Access Tokens.

You can also test the Search API by using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search?q=%22John). It automatically generates an Access Token for your testing.

Comment: I dont get my access token . I give my phone number to facbook but facebook doesnt send sms for access token . is there any other way that get the access token?

Comment: You'll have to create an APP on Facebook. Using this APP, you can retrieve an Access Token. Look at the Developers Documentation for more details.